# How to properly get value from Radiobutton on Dialog fragment to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to get the text value of radio button when button on dialog fragment clicked i use this code

```
btnOK.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(selectedId);
            LevelDialogListener activity = (LevelDialogListener)getActivity();
            activity.onFinishSelectDialog(rb.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),rb.getText()+
                   "Level Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

but i get ClassCastException on line

```
LevelDialogListener activity = (LevelDialogListener)getActivity();
```

is i do the proper way?

[EDIT]
this my dialogFrgment code:

```
public class LevelSelectDialog extends DialogFragment implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{

public interface LevelDialogListener{
    void onFinishSelectDialog(String inputText);
}

private Button btnOK;
private String sb;
private int selectedId;

public LevelSelectDialog(){
    //Empty constructor required for Dialog fragment
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_levelselect,container);
    btnOK = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDOk);
    final RadioGroup rgLevel = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rgLevel);
    getDialog().setTitle("SelectLevelDialog");

    btnOK.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(selectedId);
            LevelDialogListener activity = (LevelDialogListener)getActivity();
            activity.onFinishSelectDialog(rb.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),rb.getText()+
                   "Level Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
   selectedId = checkedId;
}
```

}

this my Fragment code:

```
package com.ibrahim.dicel;
public class Menu4RegisterFragment extends Fragment implements  LevelSelectDialog.LevelDialogListener{
Button btnLevel;

int lvlValue;
View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register,container,false);

    // Level Button Click event
    btnLevel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    showEditDialog();
                }
    });


    return rootView;
}

private void showEditDialog(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    LevelSelectDialog levelSelectDialog = new LevelSelectDialog();
    levelSelectDialog.show(fm, "dialog_levelselect");
}

@Override
public void onFinishSelectDialog(String inputText) {
    switch(inputText){
        case "Administrator":
            lvlValue = 1;
            btnLevel.setText("Administrator");
            break;
        case "Penyetuju":
            lvlValue = 2;
            btnLevel.setText("Penyetuju");
            break;
        case "Teknisi":
            lvlValue = 3;
            btnLevel.setText("Teknisi");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),inputText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I use this fragment as one of selected menu from navigaton menu

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have properly implemented Interface in your activity.
2. If so paste both your both activity and fragment code.